# Read results of SQL query while its datatype is not fixed

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I'm executing a SQL Query using `System.Data.Entity.DbContext.Database.SqlQuery`.

My SQL query is generated dynamically and it have `select @param1, @param2,...,@paramn;` at its last line. All of this `@param` variables are ID of tables which are int values.

My question is how can I read these params from SQLQuery.

Running below code:

```
DbContext.Database.SqlQuery<string>(rawQueryString)
var insertedKeyValues = result.ToList();
```

results in an exception:

> The data reader has more than one field. Multiple fields are not valid for EDM primitive or enumeration types

How can I read these int values into an array or list? I think my output data is some sort of anonymous data type but I don't know how to write the correct syntax for this.

Comment: Why are you using DataReader which will only get first parameter?

Comment: The error is pretty clear. The query contains multiple *fields* per row (not parameters, *fields*) but the return type specifies only a single parameter per row. Either provide a type that contains the correct number of parameters or use `dynamic`

Comment: Returning *parameters* in the `SELECT` clause is a bit strange too, because the code itself had to provide them in the first place. It already knows what those values are. What is the query trying to do??

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Can you help me to write the correct syntax to use `dynamic`? I want to read result values but I read that dynamic could not help (may be I'm wrong). And my problem is number of fields are not fixed and may change from run to run.

Comment: `dynamic` matches any result type. Just change `<string>` to `<dynamic>`. You havent' explained why you return the values you already know though. Unless the query uses them for temporary storage (why) and returns all of them in the end.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I dynamically create several insert queries which must be run in one transaction. I read primary key of inserted data using `scope_indentity()` and store it in a variable which declared in TSQL. Afterwards at the end of successful transaction I will return all inserted ID's and process them. I should note that Insert queries belong to different tables.

Comment: There's no reason to do that. EF already does that for the objects it controls, including using a single transaction internally to store all changes made by `SaveChanges`. That method will persist *all* changes made to the context, so there's no reason to call it more than once

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I need to return inserted keys to a user which calls my webservice method. User sends me list of items to be inserted in one  transaction. If transaction succeed, I should return list of primary key for all items inserted. Since database structure may change time to time, so there is no fixed data model and user send me list of <field,value> pairs including table name for each insert query. So i need to generate sql query dynamically as a string and run it as a raw query.  Since everything is dynamic I don't know how to read result with dynamic number of fields.

Comment: @VSB EF already does this. When you add objects whose PK is database-generated, SaveChanges will insert all of them, retrieve all new key values and update all the added objects. You can check the ID values of the added objects to get the new values. If you don't want to do that, there's no point in using EF *at all*. Just write a query script and execute it with ADO.NET

Comment: @VSB besides, how will you find which value belongs to which object or even *class*, if you don't know what the results are? If you really don't care, return the results in a single query, not as separate parameters. Eg, you could insert them into a table parameter and return the contents of that table with a single SELECT

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203469/discussion-between-vsb-and-panagiotis-kanavos).

Comment: Update the question explaining what the query does. Posting the actual query will help a *lot*. This will allow people to answer directly instead of trying to understand what's going on.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Could you please check it inside chat discussion  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59138971/read-results-of-sql-query-while-its-datatype-is-not-fixed?noredirect=1#]

Comment: Update the question with the missing information instead